# PrimaryKey need to be auto increment always?

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I am working on banking application, during the database design I have heard that primary key should be auto increment, but it is easy to use account number as primary key for the table account, which is the mixture and string and digit. So please mention is there any problem about using account_number as primary key.

Answer (score 4):

A primary key is by no means required to use the `auto_increment` property - it just needs to be a unique, not-null, identifier, so the account number would do just fine.

There are, however, two additional considerations worth keeping in mind:

1. Numbers generally take up less space than strings, which usually makes their indexes smaller, and thus faster. If you have a complicated schema and use a lot of joins on the primary key in your queries, this difference may be noticeable.
2. Some DBAs advocate the practice of having primary (and other) keys that are separate from your data. That way, if you one day change your account identifiers (e.g., the bank acquires another bank and has to incorporate its clients into its system), you'll just have to update some data, and not all your keys.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with it, and you don't need to auto_increment (but its handy).  A Primary Key just needs to be a unique value that identifies its entry from other entries, and not null.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key should be unique but not necessarily need to be auto_increment. As long is account_number is unique, there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no need that the primary key is set to auto increment if we know the primary key is always unique. We set the primary key to auto increment because it is easy to handle. As you are making a bank software, the bank account number is always unique for every user. Therefore you can use that account number as a primary key. That's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the account number is unique, immutable and never NULL, it's not a problem to use it as a primary key.

If you aren't sure about the immutability it's probably not a good idea, things change and updating a primary key is generally *not* the best idea due to the fact that you also need to update all foreign key referencing it.

If you're not sure, a [surrogate primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key#Surrogates_in_practice) along with a UNIQUE index on the account number is probably better.